# Exception occur when i deploy java spring mvc project on the jelastic

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, project, jelastic

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection

Comment: Please share some configs, sources etc.
We only can suggest you to check similar cases if you will not provide it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439611/could-not-open-hibernate-session-for-transaction-javaconfig
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112339/could-not-open-hibernate-session-for-transaction-cannot-open-connection

Answer (score 0):

I think your Hibernate configuration is accessing the database via a secure layer? In any case, you should configure your Hibernate or any ORM to connect to the database through it's INTERNAL IP address. This should fix the issue.